# TypeScript classes into Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I am learning about classes in **Typescript** and **extend**. Once I compiled **.ts** file and looked into **.js**. The code for **class** and **extend** in js is quite different. In **.js** class is made with function not with **class**.

My TS code

```
 class User4 {
      private city: string = "xyx";
      protected number: number = 123123;
      constructor(public name: string) {}
    }

    class additional extends User4 {
      method1() {
        console.log(this.number);
      }
    }

    export {};
```

While the code in **.js ** is

```
"use strict";
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(b, p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        if (typeof b !== "function" && b !== null)
            throw new TypeError("Class extends value " + String(b) + " is not a constructor or null");
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
exports.__esModule = true;
var User4 = /** @class */ (function () {
    function User4(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.city = "xyx";
        this.number = 123123;
    }
    return User4;
}());
var additional = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(additional, _super);
    function additional() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    additional.prototype.method1 = function () {
        console.log(this.number);
    };
    return additional;
}(User4));
```

I am wondering, if there is any issue with my system or its something else because the code in **.js** file is really crazy

Comment: It's not crazy, it's transpiled to ES5 which didn't have a `class` keyword

Comment: Why do you believe there is an _issue_? That's just transpiled to an older JS/ES standard which didn't have classes yet. If you want to transpile to more recent EcmaScript standards you have to configure this in your tsconfig file.

Comment: Consider targeting ES2015 or above, then check the transpiled output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have *real* classes. Classes in JS are syntax sugar, take a look at this article: [How Classes work in JavaScript](https://codeburst.io/how-classes-work-in-javascript-b12d1889048f)

You're getting this "crazy" code, because the transpiler is by default set to handle old versions of JavaScript, before `class` was even added as part of the language.

Comment: What makes a class "real"?

Comment: @Bergi being a separate structure, compiled or interpreted as something that wouldn't be just an equivalent of other language features.

Comment: So if a language is powerful enough to emulate classes it cannot have "real" classes by your definition?

Comment: There is no such language in existence ;)

Comment: Every turing-complete language can emulate classes.